# Convexity and strict convexity

Tags: geometry, analysis

When the rate of change of the increasing function is close to 0, there is no difference from the monotonic increasing function.
Similarly, there is no difference between convex and strictly convex.
By the way, I do not know the graph of the convex function.
Why is the graph of a convex function cup-shaped?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the definition of a convex function. It says that chords (secants) are always above the graph of the function. Roughly speaking, this means that the graph must be “cup” shaped.

There certainly **is** a difference between convex and strictly convex. The graph of a convex function can contain line segments, but the graph of a strictly convex one can’t. So $f(x)=|x|$ is convex, but it’s not strictly convex.